# Hibernate calling wrong setter

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some problem with the way hibernate load some beans from database.

We use an bean/beanHistoric structure in order to persists all changes made on that bean. When we persists some changes in a bean instance we create a beanHistoric with the same data and save it so in order to do that some setters are not exactly setters.
For instance:

```
@Entity
public class beanHistoric {
    List<AnotherBeanHistoric> anotherBeanListH;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="beanHistoric", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    public List<AnotherBeanHistoic> getAnotherBeanList(){
        return this.anotherBeanListH;
    }
    public void setAnotherBeanList(List<AnotherBean> anotherBeanList){
        for (AnotherBean anotherBean : anotherBeanList){
            anotherBeanListH.add(new AnotherBeanHistoric(anotherBean))
        }
    }

    private void setAnotherBeanListH(List<AnotherBeanHistoric> anotherBeanList){
        this.anotherBeanListH = anotherBeanList;
    }
}
```

As you can see the attribute is written anotherBeanListH but hibernate is calling setAnotherBeanList to populate the object once its loaded from database instead of setAnotherBeanListH.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The `setAnotherBeanListH` is private - try making it public

Comment: How is the entity mapped. Where are the annotations?

Comment: Trying it right now and it didn't work. I made it private since hibernate is supose to use reflection to populate the attributes and has access to private methods. (Also I don't want any nosy developer to use it ;-) ) Editing the question with anotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so as I was editing the question adding the anotations used in the bean I realized that my getter had the name `getAnotherBeanList` instead of `getAnotherBeanListH`.

As I was using my anotations in the getter (some legacy style I had to follow) instead of the attribute itself, seems like hibernate understood that the name of the getter was the name of the attribute so the setter to call was `getAnotherBeanList`.

Should had look a bit harder before asking this question but I think is worth knowing that this can happen.

Answer (score 2):

You told Hibernate that the property named `anotherBeanList` was mapped as a OneToMany, by annotating the getter `getAnotherBeanList()`. So, when reading the entity from the database, it populates the association by calling the associated setter: `setAnotherBeanList()`. The contrary would be quite surprising. Why would Hibernate call `setBar()` if the property is named `foo`?